# TCollection safe coding in delphi

Tags: delphi

I have the following situation.
I have created a tcollection class to handle writing into a firebird database.

```
type TLogFIREBIRDCollection = class (TCollection)
  private
    public
      function  GetItem(Index : Integer) : TLogFIREBIRD_Item;
      function  Add : TLogFIREBIRD_Item;
  end;

type TLogFIREBIRD_Item = class (TCollectionItem)
  private
      fIDWORKFLOW      : Integer;
      fOperationTypeOf : Integer;
      fTypeOf          : Integer;
      fReturn_Code     : Integer;
      fError_Code      : Integer;
      fDataEvent       : TDateTime;
      fLogMessage      : String;
      fProgram_Version : String;
      fProgram_Name    : String;
    public
      function CopyFrom (aSource : TLogFIREBIRD_Item): Boolean;

      property IDWORKFLOW      : Integer   read fIDWORKFLOW      write fIDWORKFLOW;
      property OperationTypeOf : Integer   read fOperationTypeOf write fOperationTypeOf;
      property TypeOf          : Integer   read fTypeOf          write fTypeOf;
      property Return_Code     : Integer   read fReturn_Code     write fReturn_Code;
      property Error_Code      : Integer   read fError_Code      write fError_Code;
      property DataEvent       : TDateTime read fDataEvent       write fDataEvent;
      property LogMessage      : String    read fLogMessage      write fLogMessage;
      property Program_Name    : String    read fProgram_Name    write fProgram_Name;
      property Program_Version : String    read fProgram_Version write fProgram_Version;
  end;

function TLogFIREBIRDCollection.GetItem(Index: Integer): TLogFIREBIRD_Item;
begin
  Result := inherited Items[Index] as TLogFIREBIRD_Item;
end;

function TLogFIREBIRDCollection.Add: TLogFIREBIRD_Item;
begin
  Result := inherited Add as TLogFIREBIRD_Item;
end;
```

and I have created a thread class to use the collection to keep all the items in the memory till i have "time" to write them into database. like a serialisation.

```
type
  TThreadLoggingFIREBIRD = class(TThread)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    workLog        : TLogFIREBIRD;
    workCollection : TLogFIREBIRDCollection;
  protected

  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure   Execute; override;
    procedure   DoTerminate; override;
    procedure   SignalStart;
    procedure   SignalFinish;
    procedure   Setup(aServer : String; aDatabase : String; aFirebirdUser : String; aFirebirdPass : String; aLogFolderErrors : String; aLogTableName : String; aDaysToKeep : Integer);
    procedure   WriteCollectionLog(aIDWORKFLOW : Integer; aOPERATION_TYPEOF : Integer; aTypeOf : Integer; aReturnCode : Integer; aError_Code : Integer; aDataEvent : TDateTime; aMessage : String; aProgramName : String; aProgramVersion : String);
  end;

procedure TThreadLoggingFIREBIRD.Execute;
var workItem : TLogFIREBIRD_Item;
begin
  while not Terminated do begin
    while workCollection.Count > 0 do begin
      if Terminated then begin
        Break;
      end;
      try
        workItem := workCollection.GetItem(0); <---- error line
      except
      end;
      if workItem <> nil then begin
        workLog.WriteLog(workItem.IDWORKFLOW, workItem.OperationTypeOf, workItem.TypeOf, workItem.Return_Code, workItem.Error_Code, workItem.DataEvent, workItem.LogMessage, workItem.Program_Name, workItem.Program_Version);
      end;
      try
        workCollection.Delete(0);
      except
      end;
    end;

    Sleep(1000);
  end;
end;

procedure TThreadLoggingFIREBIRD.WriteCollectionLog(aIDWORKFLOW : Integer; aOPERATION_TYPEOF : Integer; aTypeOf : Integer; aReturnCode : Integer; aError_Code : Integer; aDataEvent : TDateTime; aMessage : String; aProgramName : String; aProgramVersion : String);
var workItem : TLogFIREBIRD_Item;
begin
  workItem := workCollection.Add;
  workItem.IDWORKFLOW      := aIDWORKFLOW;
  workItem.OperationTypeOf := aOPERATION_TYPEOF;
  workItem.TypeOf          := aTypeOf;
  workItem.Return_Code     := aReturnCode;
  workItem.Error_Code      := aError_Code;
  workItem.DataEvent       := aDataEvent;
  workItem.LogMessage      := aMessage;
  workItem.Program_Name    := aProgramName;
  workItem.Program_Version := aProgramVersion;
end;
```

now i receive strage errors on "workItem := workCollection.GetItem(0);" like acces violation.
my question is...
the WriteCollectionLog is a safe one?
or more specific ... after I "workItem := workCollection.Add;"
is available in the counting mechanism of the collection therefore can be destroyed by the executed method?

if this is the case what could be the safe aproach?
regards
PS
i put the try except just in case but that is not the correct approch.

Comment: Where are you creating your `workCollection` class? The provided code doesen't show it ever being created. but then again you haven't shown constructor of your `TThreadLoggingFIREBIRD` where I'm guessing the `workCollection` class would probably created.

Comment: The OP didn't say any thing about this line `while workCollection.Count > 0 do begin` so I think the collection is created in the constructor as you guessed.  I think we also need to see these too `function  GetItem(Index : Integer) : TLogFIREBIRD_Item; function  Add : TLogFIREBIRD_Item;`. and then we will find something that would have been solved by debugging the code.

Comment: i have updated the initial code.

Comment: Well, a TCollection is not thread safe. So when one threads writes to the collection, deleting an entry from this thread might result in unexpected results (like AV’s)